# Has anybody used Ninject and the MS Enterprise Caching application block?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ninject, unity-container, enterprise-library

I am putting together a reporting service based on a very slow connection to a backing (dare I say legacy) data store. The only access I have to the data store is via a web services SDK written in java.

I have a MVC3 C# front end using `Ninject` for the DI. The list of pre-canned reports and the prompts for parameters are unlikely to change frequently. There are some prompts that I need better control over for both freshness and security (the user list).

I have done a proof of concept using the `System.Web.Caching.Cache` but it does not offer the control I need over the data in the cache. I would like to use the MS Enterprise Application Caching Block because it does offer the control. I do not want to add Unity to the application (period, 'nuff said).

Has anybody used `Ninject` to resolve the `ICacheManager` / `CacheManager`?

Comment: What exactly is the problem and what have you tried yourself?

Comment: @Steven - I'm winding my way through the various constructor binding elements and have come up against the instrumentation provider (more precisely the ICachingInstrumentationProvider).  I do not feel that I need instrumentation at this point, but there doesn't seem to be a way around this.

Comment: Isn't the Caching Block now part of System.Runtime.Caching anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems I was making this way (way, way) more complicated then it needed to be.

**Instructions to implement the Application Block Caching without Unity and without Instrumentation.**

Add the following to your config file:

```
<section name="cachingConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching.Configuration.CacheManagerSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching" requirePermission="true" />
...
<cachingConfiguration defaultCacheManager="Default">
  <cacheManagers>
    <add name="Default" expirationPollFrequencyInSeconds="60" maximumElementsInCacheBeforeScavenging="10000" numberToRemoveWhenScavenging="100" backingStoreName="NullBackingStore" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching.CacheManager, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching" />
  </cacheManagers>
  <backingStores>
    <add type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching.BackingStoreImplementations.NullBackingStore, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching" name="NullBackingStore" />
  </backingStores>
</cachingConfiguration>
```

Where you need the cache declare:

```
ICacheManager _cache = CacheFactory.GetCachemanager();
```

You can then use the full width and depth of the caching block.